# How to perform factor and canonical correlation analysis on correlation matrices in R?

Tags: r, correlation, multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis

I know how to do factor and canonical correlation analysis on raw data in *R*. But sometimes we only having correlation matrices for the data. I'd like to know any *R* functions which can take correlation matrices as input for factor and canonical correlation analysis. It is easy to write dedicated functions but it is nicer to have some built-in tested functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Ideas for factor analysis and PCA:

```
# get some Big 5 personality data and pretend we only have cor matrix and n
library(psych)
bfi <- na.omit(bfi[, 1:25])
xcor <- cor(bfi)
xn <- nrow(bfi)

# factor analysis using correlation matrix
factanal(covmat=xcor, n.obs=xn, factors=5)

# Principal components analysis using psych package
psych::principal(r=xcor, n.obs=xn, nfactors=5)
```

#### Canonical correlation analysis

- I don't think  `CCA` or `cancor` takes correlation matrices as input.
- You could use one of the sem packages in R to perform canonical correlation analysis. I know that [`sem`](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/sem/index.html) can take a correlation matrix as input.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for your nice answer. Would you like to give an example of canonical correlation analysis with sem package. Thanks

Comment: What changes in the code if I use the na.action argument from factanal() ?

Answer (score 6):

For factor analysis, the [psych](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/index.html) package accepts either raw data or a correlation matrix (see e.g., `factor.pa()`). About CCA, I'm not aware of a package that would take correlation matrices as input instead of row data tables.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old topic, but I was having the same problem and came across this page: [Canonical Correlation Analysis](http://www.stat.wmich.edu/wang/561/egs/Rcancor.html). I just tried out this guy's function for myself and it works perfectly (albeit with slightly less output than the better known R functions that only accept raw data as input). Hope this helps you or somebody like you (and me) in the future.